# Add a row when a conditions match?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a row when a condition match and fill values in all column. The below code works fine but takes a lot of time as the dataframe is pretty huge. Can this be optimized?

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['counter'][i]==1:
        df.loc[len(df)]=[df['user_id'][i],df['start_time'][i]-datetime.timedelta(seconds=1),'psuedo_App_start',np.nan,0,np.nan,0]
```

Comment: Is possible add some sample data, 5 rows?

Comment: also there are multiple `if df['counter'][i]==1:` like `if df['counter'][i]==2:`, `if df['counter'][i]==3:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for change filtered rows by `dictionary`, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to original, [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default unique index:

```
d = {'event_name':'psuedo_App_start',
     'event_desc': np.nan,
     'Notification_process':0,
     'current_screen':np.nan,
     'counter': 0}

df1 = df[df['counter'] == 1].assign(**d).copy()

#if necessary subtract one second
#df1['start_time'] -= datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
df = pd.concat([df1, df]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```